# printing multiple sections of text between two markers in python

Tags: python, parsing, text

I converted [this](https://cms.sseairtricityleague.ie/sites/default/files/inline-files/2019%20Season%20Premier%20Division%20Squad%20Numbers.pdf) page (it's squad lists for different sports teams) from PDF to text using this code:

```
import PyPDF3
import sys
import tabula
import pandas as pd


#One method
pdfFileObj = open(sys.argv[1],'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF3.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
count = 0
text = ""

while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()

print(text)
```

The output looks like this:

```
2019 SEASON 

PREMIER DIVISION SQUAD NUMBERS 
CLUB: BOHEMIANS

1

James Talbot

GK

2

Derek Pender 

DF

3

Darragh Leahy 

DF

.... some more names....

2019 SEASON 


PREMIER DIVISION SQUAD NUMBERS 
CLUB: CORK CITY 

1

Mark McNulty

GK

2

Colm Horgan

DF

3

Alan Bennett

DF
....some more names....


2019 SEASON 

PREMIER DIVISION SQUAD NUMBERS 
CLUB: DERRY CITY

1

Peter Cherrie

GK

2

Conor McDermott

DF

3

Ciaran Coll

DF
```

I wanted to transform this output to a tab delimited file with three columns: team name, player name, and number. So for the example I gave, the output would look like:

```
Bohemians   James Talbot  1
Bohemians   Derek Pender  2
Bohemians   Darragh Leahy 3
Cork City   Mark McNulty  1
Cork City   Colm Horgan   2
Cork City   Alan Bennett  3
Derry City  Peter Cherrie  1
Derry City  Conor McDermott  2
Derry City  Ciaran Coll  3
```

I know I need to first (1) Divide the file into sections based on team, and then (2) within each team section; combine each name + number field into pairs to assign each number to a name.

I wrote this little bit of code to parse the big file into each sports team:

```
import sys
fileopen = open(sys.argv[1])
recording = False
for line in fileopen:
    if not recording:
        if line.startswith('PREMI'):
            recording = True
    elif line.startswith('2019 SEA'):
            recording = False
    else:   
        print(line)
```

But I'm stuck, because the above code won't divide up the block of text **per team** (i.e. i need multiple blocks of text extracted to separate strings or lists?). Can someone advise how to divide up the text file I have per team (so in this example, I should be left with three blocks of text...and then somehow I can work on each team-divided block of text to pair numbers and names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Soooo, not necessarily true to form and I don't take into consideration the other libraries you'd used, but it was designed to give you a start. You can reformat it however you wish.**

```
>>> string = '''2019 SEASON 

PREMIER DIVISION SQUAD NUMBERS 
CLUB: BOHEMIANS

1

James Talbot

GK

2

Derek Pender 

DF

3

Darragh Leahy 

DF

.... some more names....

2019 SEASON 


PREMIER DIVISION SQUAD NUMBERS 
CLUB: CORK CITY 

1

Mark McNulty

GK

2

Colm Horgan

DF

3

Alan Bennett

DF
....some more names....


2019 SEASON 

PREMIER DIVISION SQUAD NUMBERS 
CLUB: DERRY CITY

1

Peter Cherrie

GK

2

Conor McDermott

DF

3

Ciaran Coll

DF'''



>>> def reorder(string):
        import re
        headers = ['Team', 'Name', 'Number']
        print('\n')
        print(headers)
        print()
        paragraphs = re.findall('2019[\S\s]+?(?=2019|$)', string)
        for paragraph in paragraphs:
            club = re.findall('(?i)CLUB:[\s]*([\S\s]+?)\n', paragraph)
            names_numbers = re.findall('(?i)([\d]+)[\n]{1,3}[\s]*([\S\ ]+)', paragraph)
            for i in range(len(names_numbers)):
                if len(club) == 1:
                    print(club[0]+' | '+names_numbers[i][1]+' | '+names_numbers[i][0])




>>> reorder(string)


['Team', 'Name', 'Number']

BOHEMIANS | James Talbot | 1
BOHEMIANS | Derek Pender  | 2
BOHEMIANS | Darragh Leahy  | 3
CORK CITY  | Mark McNulty | 1
CORK CITY  | Colm Horgan | 2
CORK CITY  | Alan Bennett | 3
DERRY CITY | Peter Cherrie | 1
DERRY CITY | Conor McDermott | 2
DERRY CITY | Ciaran Coll | 3
```